# How to use kendo template expression in razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I want to convert kendo expression to int and then query a list

like this;

```
<script id="history-grid-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
@(Model.Where(x => x.ID == Convert.ToInt32("#= ID #")))

</script>
```

But it gives me error.

How can i do that?

Comment: Exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Kendo evaluates any piece of code present in a text/x-kendo-template as Javascript. Here, you want to evaluate a C# expression, this is why you have an error.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to show some history data after clicking some button in your grid.

Your sample assumes that all data is present in the Model. I would not suggest to do that because it slows down your page load speed because all the data is loaded synchronously.

I would suggest to do an ajax (asynchronous) call and load your history data with this request. Something like: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command

Or if all your data is present you can take a look at: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate